# Trying to debug in Eclipse, getting error 'No Source Available for "main() at [hex number]"'

Tags: c, eclipse, debugging

My C program runs with no problem. The error is with debugging. It recognizes breakpoints and will F8 through them no problem, but no variables show up.

Here are my debug settings

[image: http://i60.tinypic.com/28peus.jpg]

[image]

[image]

Any help would be awesome, thanks

*EDIT*

Here's the code, though it doesn't matter:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){

    int i = 3;

    int j = 4;

    printf("%d %d\n", i, j);

    return 0;


}
```

Here's what the debugging window looks like. Notice the lack of variables and the error text in red:

[image]

Again, I can add breakpoints, nothing will show up in that window.

Sasikanth, I am unsure what screenshot you're asking for?

*EDIT 2*

Ahhh, I see. Here's the requested scrnshot

[image]

Anyone got any idea?

Comment: Please add a screenshot of the debugger settings as well (the debugger tab in your debug configurations window

Comment: In the debug configuration Window, there's a debugger tab.  Please share a screen shot of the settings on that tab

Comment: Edited and added scrnshot

Comment: Disable stop on startup at  checkbox. Also,  in the shared libraries tab, there should be some option to automatically load shared library symbols or something like that. Disable that as well, put a breakpoint in your code and launch

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Tried both of those, same result :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I was actually able to solve this. After a lot of research, I realized my gdb.exe file was way out of date. Update MinGW fixed it (so it wasn't an Eclipse problem)

Thanks for the attempts at helping!

Comment: Plus one and thanks for posting the solution to help others, like me, who have the same problem in future